# How to say "to woo" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request

How does one say "to woo" or "to court" (i.e., to solicit someone for marriage) in Latin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One definition (10.c in *Oxford Latin dictionary*) of *petere* is 'to seek the hand of (a woman) in marriage; also *~ere in coniugium* or *matrimonium*.' For example, in Livy, *Ab urbe condita* 40.4.3, we find:

> *Theoxena multis petentibus aspernata nuptias est.*
>
> Although many were seeking her hand, Theoxena rejected marriage.

The noun for 'suitor' or 'wooer' is *procus*. In *Metamorphoses* 13.735, to take one example, Ovid combines the noun *procus* and the verb *petere*:

> *hanc multi petiere proci...*
>
> Many suitors courted her...

There's also the related verb *procare*. that's used in fr. 7 (according to the numbering in Morel's edition) of Livius Andronicus's *Odyssia*:

> *matrem <proci> procitum plurimi venerunt.*
>
> A great many suitors came to court my mother.